# How to create empty folder in java?

Tags: java, createfile, create-directory

I tried to use the *File class* to create an empty file in a directory like "C:/Temp/Emptyfile".
However, when I do that, it shows me an error : "already made folder Temp". Otherwise, it won't create one for me.

So, how do I literally create folders with java API?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Looks file you use the `.mkdirs()` method on a `File` object: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-create-directory.shtml

```
// Create a directory; all non-existent ancestor directories are
// automatically created
success = (new File("../potentially/long/pathname/without/all/dirs")).mkdirs();
if (!success) {
    // Directory creation failed
}
```

Answer (score 104):

You can create folder using the following Java code:

```
File dir = new File("nameoffolder");
dir.mkdir();
```

By executing above you will have folder 'nameoffolder'  in current folder.

Comment: do import File class in above code like this  -

import java.io.File;

Comment: package is imported in java exactly, not class

Comment: @RiponAlWasim can you elaborate more ?

Comment: You can write as import java.io.*; or, mentioning specific class as import java.io.File; Anyway, import statement is not the main focus of the question

Comment: it does not work with me !