# creating folders in ID based java application

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

I am trying to Build a Java application that requires a login for user to enter. What i want to do is when ever i add a new user i want a folder to be created for the user so that person can only add and remove things from his/her folder.
Im still new to java so if someone can explain this to me in simple words would be great!

Comment: Can you give us more information about the nature of your solution?  For example, will user's folders be created on the local machine which is running the java application, or will the java application be running on a server?

Comment: the folders will be created on a server which all computers running the application are always connected to.

Comment: your question is you want to create folder using java?

Comment: I want to create an application using java that creates folders when a new user is added to it. So when the user enters the application using his UserID he can upload or display text/files only from his folder.

Comment: Try checking the following questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571496/how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801971/how-to-create-empty-folder-in-java